# JSON adds extra contents to a single file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have code that works something like this

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_json("filename.json", orient = 'split')
```

In my actual code, the files are typically a few thousands rows long and they have string, date and numeric columns.

This code works fine about 95% of the time, but sometimes it writes extra contents to the file.

Instead of looking like this-

```
{"columns":["calories","duration"],"index":[0,1,2],"data":[[420,50],[380,40],[390,45]]}
```

It will look like this -

```
{"columns":["calories","duration"],"index":[0,1,2],"data":[[420,50],[380,40],[390,45]]}, [380, 40], [390, 45]]}
```

One easy way for me to spot when it happens is that there is always two `}` symbols.

Is this a known issue and, if so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: That looks like the file previously had longer JSON, and it was overwritten without truncating. But `to_json()` won't do that. Is there something else writing the same file?

Comment: So what it's creating is invalid JSON, or is there a matching `{` somewhere in the output?

Comment: Can you try `df.to_json(open("filename.json", "w"), orient = 'split')` ?

Comment: Yes, @Barmar is correct that `to_json()` explicitly passes `w` so this shouldn't happen. [the code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4bfe3d07b4858144c219b9346329027024102ab6/pandas/io/json/_json.py#L128)

Comment: I have one job that writes to json files and another job that reads those json files and does other stuff to them. Is it possible that those jobs are colliding and that's causing this error?

Comment: Yes, this is most likely two jobs writing the file at the same time, resulting in a mix of the data from both.

Comment: The second job only reads from the file. It doesn't write

Comment: Make it an issue on pandas's github page if not already have made

Comment: Extra contents have a space after the comma. Since there is no such option in pandas to_json, it is probably happening somewhere else. If you terminate the program immediately after to_json (by calling `exit(0)` ), do you still get the same result?